# Place div inside images with different widths

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am trying to put a div that is always in the same position (bottom right) on all images.

My problem is that if an image occupies 100% width the div goes to the center :(

How can I put this div on the images, always in the lower right corner, even if I have images with different widths?

```
.boxImage {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    background-position: 13px 13px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    width: 44%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 91%;
    left: 43%;
    max-width: 250px;
}


<div class="d">
    <div class="a">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.ibb.co/mqnwwKB/Screenshot-72.jpg">
      <!-- <img class="img-fluid Images" src="https://i.ibb.co/3p3D4h6/dmitry-bayer-276d-F1-RG67-Q-unsplash.jpg"> -->
  <div class="row b">       
    <ul class="list-inline rating-list" *ngFor="let star of stars" style="display: inline-block">
      <li (click)="countStar(star)" [ngClass]="{'selected': (star <= selectedValue)}">
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: make div position relative to image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following classes in your css file. This will make your white box's position relative to the image.

```
.abc{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.abc .boxImage{
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
}
```

**Working Demo**: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z2n2p3)

Comment: Your link must be incorrect, this is the same as the post :)

Comment: @Paulsk let me check

Comment: @ Himanshu Singh  
In this solution there is only one problem ... in the image with smaller width, the div comes out of the image :(

Comment: @Paulsk answer edited, just add above mentioned code in your css file.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple achieve this using a simple `container` like a `div` that as a `position: relative` just like this:

```css
.img-box-ctn {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.boxImage {
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 9%;
    left: 43%;
    background-color: white;
    background-position: 13px 13px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    width: 44%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    opacity: 1;
    
    max-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="drop" >
    <div class="abc">
      <div class="img-box-ctn">
      
      <img class="img-fluid Images" src="https://i.ibb.co/mqnwwKB/Screenshot-72.jpg">
      <!-- <img class="img-fluid Images" src="https://i.ibb.co/3p3D4h6/dmitry-bayer-276d-F1-RG67-Q-unsplash.jpg"> -->
      <div class="boxImage">
          <div class="row divBtn">
              <a class="toggle-one">
                  <span class="nav-link btnZ"></span>
                </a>
              <a class="toggle-two">
                <span class="nav-link btnT"></span>
              </a>
              <a class="toggle-three">
                <span class="nav-link btnR"></span>
              </a>
              <a class="toggle-four">
                <span class="nav-link btnP"></span>
              </a>
           </div>
        <ul class="list-inline rating-list" style="display: inline-block">
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>      
    </div>

  </div>
```

Check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nka15oes/9/) the JsFiddle

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me! I tested using both images and the div is not in the same position on both images :(

Comment: The div is aligned to the image with a relative size using `%` so if the images have different sizes it's a normal behaviour.

Comment: I tested with px and it still didn't work, but it's "responsive"